# TCP Timeout using poll

Tags: unix, network-programming

I am currently trying to add a timeout to a method which opens up a tcp connection. I am roughly using the guide found [here](http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?pid=13486) except that I am trying to use `poll()` instead of select. However my call to `poll()` immediately returns notifying that the fd is ready for write, although the connection is not open. Here is an reduced code example I produced:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <poll.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
   struct addrinfo hints;

   ::memset( &hints, 0, sizeof( hints ) );
   hints.ai_socktype = 0;
   hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
   hints.ai_protocol = 0;
   hints.ai_flags = AI_CANONNAME;


   struct addrinfo * info;

   if( ::getaddrinfo( "127.0.0.1", "49999", &hints, &info ) != 0 ) {
      std::cerr << "Error: getaddrinfo" << std::endl;
      exit( 1 );
   }


   int soc;

   if( (soc = ::socket( info->ai_family, info->ai_socktype, info->ai_protocol ) ) < 0 ) {
      std::cerr << "Erorr: socket" << std::endl;
   }

   // Set mode to non-blocking for timeout handling
   int arg;
   if( (arg = ::fcntl( soc, F_GETFL, 0 )) < 0 ) {
      std::cerr << "Error: fcntl" << std::endl;
      exit( 1 );
   }

   arg |= O_NONBLOCK;
   if( ::fcntl(soc, F_SETFL, arg) < 0) {
      std::cerr << "Error: fcntl" << std::endl;
      exit( 1 );
   }

   int res = ::connect(soc,info->ai_addr,info->ai_addrlen);

   if( (res != 0) && (errno != EINPROGRESS) ) {
      std::cerr << "Error: connect" << std::endl;
      exit( 1 );
   }

   pollfd pfd;
   pfd.fd = soc;
   pfd.events = POLLOUT;

   res = ::poll( &pfd, 1, 50000 );

   if( res < 0 ) {
      std::cerr << "Error: poll" << std::endl;
      exit( 1 );
   }
   else if( res == 0 ) {
      std::cerr << "Error: poll" << std::endl;
      exit( 1 );
   }

   // Set blocking mode again
   if( (arg = ::fcntl(soc, F_GETFL, NULL)) < 0) {
      std::cerr << "Error: fcntl" << std::endl;
      exit( 1 );
   }
   arg &= (~O_NONBLOCK);
   if( ::fcntl(soc, F_SETFL, arg) < 0) {
      std::cerr << "Error: fcntl" << std::endl;
      exit( 1 );
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Since port `49999` is closed on my machine I expect an error. Instead the program finishes with a return value of `0`.

I also tried to use the select example found in the link above. If I replace the call to `poll()` with the full example I get the following error message:

`Operation now in progress: Operation now in progres`

I tried to reduce the code using select, but when I reduce it, I get a correct `connection refused message`.

**EDIT**:

Note: The "Operation now in progress" message was due to an error in the error handling code on my side. Once I corrected this, I got the correct error message from "getsockopt()". This also explains why I was not able to reduce this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the missing `getsockopt()` calls. I was assuming `poll()` would return an error if the `connect()` does not succeed, but it just goes through as soon as the state can be determined. Once I added the `getsockopt()` calls from the example it worked just fine.

Here is some (not so clean) example code using poll:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <poll.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
   struct addrinfo hints;

   ::memset( &hints, 0, sizeof( hints ) );
   hints.ai_socktype = 0;
   hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
   hints.ai_protocol = 0;
   hints.ai_flags = AI_CANONNAME;


   struct addrinfo * info;

   if( ::getaddrinfo( "127.0.0.1", "49999", &hints, &info ) != 0 ) {
      std::cerr << "Error: getaddrinfo" << std::endl;
      exit( 1 );
   }


   int soc;

   if( (soc = ::socket( info->ai_family, info->ai_socktype, info->ai_protocol ) ) < 0 ) {
      std::cerr << "Erorr: socket" << std::endl;
   }

   // Set mode to non-blocking for timeout handling
   int arg;
   if( (arg = ::fcntl( soc, F_GETFL, 0 )) < 0 ) {
      std::cerr << "Error: fcntl" << std::endl;
      exit( 1 );
   }

   arg |= O_NONBLOCK;
   if( ::fcntl(soc, F_SETFL, arg) < 0) {
      std::cerr << "Error: fcntl" << std::endl;
      exit( 1 );
   }

   int res = ::connect(soc,info->ai_addr,info->ai_addrlen);

   if( res < 0 ) {
      if( errno == EINPROGRESS ) {
         pollfd pfd;
         pfd.fd = soc;
         pfd.events = POLLOUT;

         std::cout << "Polling" << std::endl;
         res = ::poll( &pfd, 1, 50000 );

         if( res < 0 ) {
            std::cerr << "Error: poll" << std::endl;
            exit( 1 );
         }
         else if( res == 0 ) {
            std::cerr << "Error: poll" << std::endl;
            exit( 1 );
         } else {
            socklen_t lon = sizeof(int);
            int valopt;
            if (getsockopt(soc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (void*)(&valopt), &lon) < 0) {
               fprintf(stderr, "Error in getsockopt() %d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
               exit(0);
            }
            // Check the value returned...
            if (valopt) {
               fprintf(stderr, "Error in delayed connection() %d - %s\n", valopt, strerror(valopt));
               exit(0);
            }
         }
      }
      else {
         std::cerr << "Error: connect" << std::endl;
         exit( 1 );
      }
   }

   // Set blocking mode again
   if( (arg = ::fcntl(soc, F_GETFL, NULL)) < 0) {
      std::cerr << "Error: fcntl" << std::endl;
      exit( 1 );
   }
   arg &= (~O_NONBLOCK);
   if( ::fcntl(soc, F_SETFL, arg) < 0) {
      std::cerr << "Error: fcntl" << std::endl;
      exit( 1 );
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I was assuming poll() would return an error if the connect() does not succeed". You were wrong to assume that. `connect()` does nothing except block until the socket becomes writable or the timeout expires. It's `connect()` that returns an error if it fails, and your code didn't check for it properly. You have now fixed that by only polling if the `connect()` returned `EAGAIN`; in other words you have implemented my answer. Whether you realize it or not.

Comment: Yes, I noticed I was wrong to assume that it would return an error. However the missing check for `EINPROGRESS` is not the problem which confused me. In my later tests, the code always got to the line `fprintf(stderr, "Error in delayed connection() %d - %s\n", valopt, strerror(valopt));` so just adding the check for `EINPROGRESS` would have not done anything as it was that check using `getsockopt()` which was missing (or that line being faulty in the other case). Still you warned me about a potential future bug, which could have led to more trouble debugging later.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to do the poll if the connect didn't succeed. It usually succeeds straight away when connecting to "localhost".

Comment: Ok, that could be one thing I may have to change, but not the root cause of the problem. The connection did not succeed (it can't since the port is closed on localhost). The problem is with the poll going through and returning a fd although there is no connection at all.